# Ext JS 6.2.0 How to clone existing rows and append the grid

Tags: extjs, clone, extjs6.2

I'm creating a clone function in our system. So far, I can copy the selected rows and add to the store, but the cloned data is not displaying in the grid. The number of records is incrementing, but the displayed data is not. Here are the snippets of the code I've done so far:

```
{
                    text:'Clone',
                    id: 'dynamicGrammarCloneBtn',
                    disabled: true,

                    listeners: {
                        click: function(panel) {
                            Ext.Msg.confirm('Clone Data', 
                            'Are you sure you want to clone the selected data?',
                            function(button){
                                if(button == 'yes'){
                                    let selectedRecords = Ext.getCmp('dynamicGrammarGrid').getSelection();
                                    if(selectedRecords.length > 0){
                                        view.getController().addActions("cloneRow",selectedRecords);
                                        view.getController().editPageToolBarInfo();
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        Ext.Msg.alert('Warning', 'Please select atleast one row to clone.');
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    },

                },
```

Then a switch case if the Clone button is clicked

```
case 'cloneRow': {

            Ext.getCmp('dynamicGrammarSaveBtn').setDisabled(false);

            var cloneGrammar  = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('insertedDynamicGrammarStore');
            
            result.forEach(function(item) {
                var originalRecord = item.data;
                var clonedRecord = Ext.apply({}, originalRecord);
                cloneGrammar.add(clonedRecord);
            });
            
            cloneGrammar.load();
            Ext.getCmp('dynamicGrammarGrid').getView().refresh();

            console.log(cloneGrammar.getData().items)
            Ext.getCmp('is_adding_row').setValue(Number(Ext.getCmp('is_adding_row').getValue()) - 1);
            

            ActionstoresTemp.addNewAction(result, "cloneRow");
              
            break;
        }
```

Then, this is the editPageToolbarInfo

```
editPageToolBarInfo: function()
{

    console.log(Ext.getCmp('dynamicGrammarGrid').getStore().getTotalCount());
    var start = 1;
    var limit = Ext.getCmp('dynamicGrammarGrid').getStore().getPageSize();
    var page = Ext.getCmp('dynamicGrammarGrid').getStore().currentPage;
    var initTotal = Ext.getCmp('dynamicGrammarGrid').getStore().getTotalCount();

    var addedRows  = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('insertedDynamicGrammarStore').data.items.length;
    var deletedRows = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('deletedDynamicGrammarStore').data.items.length;
    console.log("Added rows: ", addedRows);

    var startingPage = (((limit * page)  - limit) + start);

    console.log("limit " + limit +  " page" + page + " initTotal" + initTotal + " start" + start);
    if(initTotal < 1)
    {
        Ext.getCmp('dynamicGrammarDisplayMsg').setHtml('No records to display');

    }
    else {

        var total = initTotal + (addedRows - deletedRows);
        console.log("limit " + limit +  " page" + page + " initTotal" + initTotal + " start" + start);
        var inBetweenPage = 0;
        if((limit * page) > total){
            inBetweenPage = total;
        }
        else{
            inBetweenPage = (limit * page);
        }

        Ext.getCmp('dynamicGrammarDisplayMsg').setHtml('Displaying records ' + startingPage + ' - ' + inBetweenPage + ' of ' + total)

    }
},
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing because this is my first time working with this framework. Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: If you add a model to the store, the grid should refresh automatically. But you call `load` on the store, is this a remote store or local?

Comment: The store is local. I'm calling the load because the grid is not displaying the cloned data, so it's just for debugging purposes. Right now I'm stuck, I've already tried different methods

Comment: Try to use the `copy` method of the model you'd like to clone. Like `var clonedRecord = originalRecord.copy();`.

Comment: thanks peter, my issue is solved. i just set the id to null and then insert the new row so the grid will display the cloned records

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the most common issue here is adding the record to the store with same id.

When we try to add a new record, and if store already has record with same id, then it simply updates its own copy, doesn't create a new record. You need to delete the id from the cloned record and then add it. Or you can pass null to the record.copy method to do same.

Check this Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3od1

Accept this as an answer if it helped you.

Comment: thank you, this helped! you're correct, the grid is not displaying duplicate record with the same id

Comment: That's great! Thanks for accepting as an answer!